# Drawing a lot of images in paintcomponent method is time consuming

Tags: java, paintcomponent

```
for (int i = 0; i < bricksList.size(); i++) {
 BufferedImage image;
 try {

            image = ImageIO.read(new File(bricksList.get(i).img));

            g.drawImage(image, bricksList.get(i).x, bricksList.get(i).y, null); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

I am trying to draw 80 images using paintComponent() method. I also have another object which when I press right arrow key, keeps on moving right, when pressed left arrow key, it keeps on moving left, and so on (using keypressed event). But as every time paint component is called so the movement of that other movable object becomes very slow. How can I give a smooth running. How can I stop the bricks to get painted every time?

Comment: why are you reading in the image file every time you draw it ? just read it once and store it as a variable, draw that. File IO is normally a big bottleneck in games

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Remember that paintComponent is often called several times per second.  That is why expensive operations like reading files should never take place in it.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that your code excerpt comes out of your `paintComponent()` method, you are doing far more work there than you ought to do.  On every update, your `paintComponent()` must read each file from disk (I/O is very costly), and construct a `BufferedImage` from its contents (not necessarily cheap).  Then it just discards the image, which seems likely to be at least tens of kB in size, which will eventually start putting pressure on the GC.

Unless you have some reason to expect that the image files will be modified while your program is running (and maybe even if they *will* be modified) you could dramatically improve performance by reading all the files once each, and holding on to the `BufferedImage` objects for repeated use by `paintComponent()`.  If the relative positions of the images do not change, then you could even consider constructing one big image from their contents, and letting `paintComponent()` paint just that.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your printComponent method by a huge factor by loading your images beforehand

Create a list like BricksListImgs, in your constructor, do

```
Image BricksListImgs[];

MyConstructor () {
  BricksListImgs = new BricksListImgs[bricksList.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < bricksList.size(); i++) {
    BricksListImgs[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(bricksList.get(i).img));
  }
}
```

Then draw the images from BriksListImgs in your paintComponent method